# Unable to run quasar dev: Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, cryptography, quasar

I have an application developped in view with quasar.

I can't launch my quasar application because I have the following error:

```
 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/eciesjs/dist/utils.js

Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto"
Did you forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto

 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/futoin-hkdf/hkdf.js

Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto"
Did you forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto

 App •  ERROR  •  UI  in ./node_modules/scryptsy/lib/scrypt.js

Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "crypto"
Did you forget to install it? You can run: yarn add crypto


 App •  COMPILATION FAILED  • Please check the log above for details.
```

I tried `yarn add` and `npm install` but it still doesn't work I don't understand.

These are the `eciesjs` and `scryptsy` libraries that use "crypto".

I tried to ignore them in the package.json with

```
{
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false    
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work either

Comment: What is the exact command you used to install `crypto`?

Comment: yarn add crypto

Answer (score 0):

Straight from Quasar v2 upgrade guide (which uses Webpack v5) https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#nodejs-polyfills :

Webpack v5 removed the Nodejs polyfills for the web client builds. If you are using packages for the web client that rely on Nodejs API (they shouldn’t!), you will get errors saying that some packages are missing. Examples: Buffer, crypto, os, path.

These need to be addressed by the package owners. But if you don’t want to wait and just want to run your app/website (with a bit of risk), then you can manually install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin (yarn add --dev node-polyfill-webpack-plugin) then reference it in quasar.config.js > build > chainWebpack. Example:

```
// quasar.config.js
build: {
  chainWebpack (chain) {
    const nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin')
    chain.plugin('node-polyfill').use(nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin)
  }
}
```